# What's the use of returning true and false here?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
  var uid_len = uid.value.length;

  if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
    alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
    uid.focus(); //is this focus will be on alert box?  
    return false; //what is use of this false ?
  }

  return true; //what is use of this true?
}
```

Comment: OK OK..I GOT THE ANSWER FORM A SEARCH!

Comment: It is considered good manners to share the answer you found so that other people can learn from it when they hit this question.

Comment: THANKS JEREMY,,,THANKS FOE MOTIVATING ME:)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing where the code is called from, one can't be totally sure... but more than likely it is called from an DOM0 event handler (assigned by an `<element>.onclick=`)

The false would prevent the default action from happening, and true would allow it.

```
function userid_validation(uid,mx,my)
{
  var uid_len = uid.value.length;
  if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx)
  {
    alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);
    uid.focus(); //is this focus will be on alert box?
    return false; //what is use of this false ? 
  }
return true; //what is use of this true? 
}
```

Comment: its a simple form validation function for a userid textbox.........but it is again struking my mind...false means exit and true means go on...so why its needed to write return true?obviously it will leave the loop...

Comment: If a function doesn't specify otherwise, it will return `undefined` which is a `falsey` value.  (A `falsey` value is one that will be false if you force it to a boolean.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it prevents bubling of event. It is common practice to prevent standard behaviour of links and forms (prevent redirecting and submitting).